# How To Access Object From Spring Service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, annotations

I'm fairly new to using Spring Boot and I'm using [this tutorial](https://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/How-To-Load-CSV-File-On-Application-Start-Up-In-Spring-Boot) as a guide on how to set up a service. And it's pretty good, but I don't understand how I ultimately access the countryArray object from the main method in my Application.java class. Could someone please explain?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question, currently you want to access the **countryArray** list which will be populated by the init method of your Spring service and this list will be populated once the Spring service is initialized. I suggest you should have a **public** getter method that will allow you to read the object.

Additionally, while accessing the getter method you should not  initialize your service class using *new class()* but instead get the singleton object using `springcontext.getbean("nameofyourbean")`

Answer (score 1):

First of all. Don't use @PostConstruct. That's not very testable.
You could implement the InitializingBean-Interface and init your class there.

Second: constructor-injection is good-bractice to make your code testable.
IMHO better than @Autowired. Both is possible. It's more a matter of taste ;-)

As an alternative you could create a @Configuration class which creates a @Bean with a name. E.g.:

```
@Configuration
public class CountryConfig {
  @Bean(name = "countries")
  public Collection<Country> countries() {
    List<Country> countries = new ArrayList<>();
    // add countries here or load from repository
    return countries;
  }
}


@Service
public class CountryService {

    private final Collection<Country> countries;

    public CountryService(@Qualifier("countries") Collection<Country> countries) {
      this.countries = countries;
    }
}
```

**To answer your question**

You don't want to do something in your application's main class.
If you're creating a web-application, you have controllers which are calling service methods (see spring-boot-starter-web); or you can have schedulers (see spring schedulers); services which are calling other services or repositories.
There you can access methods / properties as you're used to in java.

If your application is a start-do something-stop application (don't get the name atm) or is a GUI based application, overthink the use of spring.